# How to add raised text to an imported STL file for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-view, text-object

I'm new to modeling and 3D printing and have a long way to go... but 1 of the reasons I got a 3D printer was practical/functional use at my family farm.  What really caught my eye was the ability to print cattle ear tags.  I found a design
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2950135
and all I have to do is edit and update the name and number on it, but struggling with that part. From the online help, I thought it was under
Mode
*Edit Mode*.

Menu
*3D Viewport ‣ Text*
but I can't find the 3D Viewport - Text part.
Can someone help give me a little nudge on this, please?
Thanks

Jim

Comment: Shift+A choose Text

Comment: When I do shift+A i get a Mesh Menu and if I move mouse it menu goes away.  I also tried selecting the existing text also and doing that, gives me same results. Thanks again for the help

Comment: You are probably in edit mode. Switch to object mode with TAB key than use Shift+A

Comment: Ok, that got me to the menu, but when I went to object mode, it didn't show/see the existing part.  double click on "sketch 2". A dialog will appear. Leave this dialog on the screen.
move cursor over the text until highlighted, right click and select "edit text". (Each line is a separate entry).
replace text with your own and click on the green tick.
when all lines of text are edited as you want, click on the green tick for sketch 2.
In the "Parts" list, right click on "Cattle ear tag" and select "Export..."
Select "STL" in the Format drop list.
The rest should be self explanatory

Comment: it might not be just text, it might be a "raised" piece of the tag.

Comment: What are you talking about?  You are following tutorial for online app OnShape? How does this relates to Blender? Please edit your question to be more clear what do you want to achieve in Blender. If you need just edit text how OnShape online app.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  No, I have not used OnShape, can't afford $1500 a year for that.  So I'm just trying to translate those steps to Blender so I can change the info on the tag.

Comment: I would suggest to you share your file so we can see what are you dealing with.

Comment: Is there a way to attach it here in this?  Here is the url  https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2950135/files    on there Maxi_179.stl is the file I'm using

Comment: Proper way to attach a blend file is via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com given code place into your question (not a comment) via "edit" link.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=DXzAS5WK" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DXzAS5WK/)

Comment: As I wrote paste the code into your question (the main text on top not into a comment like you did it right now ... Thank you

Comment: :-) Thank you.  On the front of that, there are 3 lines that kinda stand up/out.  The first DALBY, I would like to edit/change that.  The second one, the 412 number i don't need.  Then I want to change the 179 number.

Answer (score 2):

When importing STL change Scale to 0.001 to get proper size ... right now your Cattle has a dimension 73 x 99 m.

[image]

Now add a Text object ...

[image]

... that becomes big by default so scale <kbd>S</kbd> it down

[image]

WIth <kbd>Tab</kbd> switch to edit mode type your text. Add Solidify modifier to get thickness of letters.

[image]

*Search* for **Convert to Mesh**, hide this object in Outliner Editor. Select Cattle object add **Boolean modifier** kind **Union** and as *Object* select your Text object.

[image]

Before export use again Convert to Mesh (or apply modifier under arrow down icon) to make manifold object. ready for 3D printer.

---

*I would suggest to you check some tutorial for beginners to get friendly with blenders UI first.*

Comment: Thank you, I plan on doing those, we are just in calving season and needed the tags, I know I have a lot to learn, was just trying to print these out to use.

Comment: I'm not asking you to become a master, just watch a few simple videos to get familiar with interface (3x 10mins) seems to me effective at the beginning than be a "blind" :) Good luck with your work. BTW if you are in a calving season you have to have very fast 3d printer ... :)

Comment: yes... we normally don't have calves this early, but family circumstances pushed us this year.  Want to get tags in calves ears before we put them out on the pasture.  Thank you again for all your help. :-)